# Min distance between Point Cloud (XYZ) Points in Python

Tags: python, distance, point-clouds

I am trying to run Density-Based Spatial Clustering (DBSCAN) on a Point Cloud dataset which is a series of points with x,y,z coordinates. One of the parameters in min distance. How do I find the minimal distance between a point and another in space **in Python**? Many thanks!

Data Sample:
[image]

Comment: You try scipy.spatial.distance ?  More specifically, something along the lines of  A = pdist(B, 'euclidean')  where B is your list of [(X1,Y1,Z1), (X2,Y2,Z2),(X3, Y3, Z3), ..., (Xn,Yn,Zn)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can write a function that computes the euclidian distance between two points represented as numpy arrays :

```py
import numpy as np

distance = lambda p1, p2: np.sqrt(np.sum((p1 - p2) ** 2, axis=0))
```

I can't think of anything better than the naive O(n²) to find the minimum distance :

```py
import itertools

def min_distance(cloud):
  pairs = itertools.combinations(cloud, 2)
  return np.min(map(lambda pair: distance(*pair), pairs))
```

Finally, you just need to get the points from your file, I will assume that it looks like this :

*cloud.csv*

```
x, y, z
1.2, 3.4, 2.55
2.77, 7.34, 23.4
5.66, 64.3, 4.33
```

```py
def get_points(filename):
  with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    rows = np.genfromtxt(file, delimiter=',', skip_header=True)
  return rows
```

## Final code

```py
import itertools
import numpy as np

distance = lambda p1, p2: np.sqrt(np.sum((p1 - p2) ** 2, axis=0))


def min_distance(cloud):
  pairs = itertools.combinations(cloud, 2)
  return np.min(map(lambda pair: distance(*pair), pairs))


def get_points(filename):
  with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    rows = np.genfromtxt(file, delimiter=',', skip_header=True)
  return rows


filename = 'cloud.csv'
cloud = get_points(filename)
min_dist = min_distance(cloud)

print(min_dist)
```

**Output**

```
21.277006368378046
```

## Edit

As [Amiga500](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8722421/amiga500) points out, it is possible to use `scipy.spatial.distance`. We can then rewrite `min_distance` as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

min_distance = lambda cloud: np.min(pdist(cloud))
```

Comment: Thanks [tag:Rostan]! How would your answer change if you incorporate the comment by Amiga500 above in using scipy.spatial.distance?

Comment: Thank you for your edit @Rostan ! Great answer!

Comment: Hello! When I do print(min_distance), it returns "<map object at 0x0000021BACD92A48>" or "print(min_distance)<function <lambda> at 0x0000021BACD7D9D8>". Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

This is a supplement to Rostan's answer. His/her method works, but it can be improved (mainly the speed, depending on the amount of data you have it could be really worth it).

By googling "minimum distance of points" I found the following article:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/closest-pair-of-points-using-divide-and-conquer-algorithm/

The algorithm there should work for you. You also have Python code samples in the article, that should help.

Answer (score 0):

Appending to Rostan's answer, To answer Maximus's question in the comments.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
    
min_distance = lambda cloud: np.min(pdist(cloud))
print(min_distance(cloud))
```

The lambda function returns a function. You need to call it with the data to get the results.

(I don't have enough reputation points to comment, so adding this as an answer.)

## For large sets of points

Finds the distances to the nearest neighbors and returns the smallest distance.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

# assume data stored as [x, y, z] numpy array called 'cloud'

tree = cKDTree(cloud) 
nn1_dist = tree.query(cloud, k=2, workers=-1)[0][:,1]
nn1_dist = nn1_dist[nn1_dist != 0]  # remove 0s
np.min(nn1_dist)
```